# Find multiple values at a time in an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array `A=[2, 5, 8, 3]`.

How can I find at a time whether `2` and `3` exist in the array or not?

Please reply soon.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[2,3].all? { |item| A.include?(item) }`

Comment: Do you want to know whether *both* 2 and 3 exist, or if at *least one of* 2 or 3 exist?

Comment: both will be exist, not any one.

Comment: "Please reply soon." Please understand that sites like Stack Overflow don't operate at your speed. They work at the convenience of those answering, for free, in their spare time, which can be measured in days.

Comment: Have you tried `if a.include?(2) && a.include?(3)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how efficient this would be for large arrays, but this works:

```
> a = [2, 5, 8, 3]
 => [2, 5, 8, 3]

> b = [2, 3]
 => [2, 3]
> (a & b) == b
 => true

> c = [1,2]
 => [1, 2]
> (a & c) == c
 => false
```

See the '&' operator for Array.  You might also look into the Set class.  Good chance it has a better solution.

Comment: I know it was a silly question. Actually i'm new in ruby. Thanks for your answer. I'll look into the set class.